# IR Kernel dying with fresh install of Jupyter

Tags: python, r, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

This is my hardware

> ```
> :~/Downloads$ lscpu
> Architecture:          x86_64
> CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
> Byte Order:            Little Endian
> CPU(s):                4
> ```

This is my OS

> ```
> uname -a
> Linux   4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:33:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
> ```

This is my Jupyter Information

> ```
> Jupyter notebook.
>
> The version of the notebook server is 4.2.1 and is running on:
>
> Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06) 
> [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]
> ```

I Installed the R Essentials Package using https://www.continuum.io/blog/developer/jupyter-and-conda-r

But the IR Kernel dies as soon as I try to make a new R notebook. Anyone using Jupyter and R with the solution?

**Error messages**

> The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.

and

> Dead kernel
>
> The kernel has died, and the automatic restart has failed. It is
>   possible the kernel cannot be restarted. If you are not able to
>   restart the kernel, you will still be able to save the notebook, but
>   running code will no longer work until the notebook is reopened.

My Question is Python works fine but the R version dies. How do I use R from within Jupyter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is a version compatibility issue. At this moment, IRkernel has not been upgraded to the most IPython/Jupyter version. If you tried to install *de novo* in R or RStudio:

```
devtools::install_github('IRkernel/IRkernel')
IRkernel::installspec(name = 'ir33', displayname = 'R 3.3')
```

Or you could check as follows (equivalent to above) in R or RStudio:

```
library(devtools)
install_github('IRkernel/IRkernel')
library(IRkernel)
installspec(name = 'ir33', displayname = 'R 3.3') ##update your R version according to check which version of R you have
 R.version.string
```

You'd get an error message:

> Jupyter or IPython **3.0** has to be installed but could neither run
>   “jupyter” nor “ipython”, “ipython2” or “ipython3”.

The best thing to do here is wait for the developers' upgrade. Hopefully they'll resolve the issue soon.

If you absolutely need the issue to be resolved at this moment, you should install the historical versions of IPython and run the command above:
[Link to IPython 3.x Series](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/whatsnew/version3.html)

Answer (score 0):

Did you install R before Jupyter? If so, I faced the same situation and solved by uninstalling and re-installing in a specified order:

[R is dead in Jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49368716/r-is-dead-in-jupyter/52287134#52287134)