# R is dead in Jupyter

Tags: macos, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

I have instaled R in my jupyter through anaconda and It was working fine. Today I found this message when I opened R form Jupyter and I don't know what is the problem ?

> The kernel has died, and the automatic restart has failed. It is possible the kernel cannot be restarted. If you are not able to restart the kernel, you will still be able to save the notebook, but running code will no longer work until the notebook is reopened.

I'm using Mac OSX

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in Mac OSX when R is installed before Anaconda. The fix is to:
1. Uninstall R and Anaconda
2. Install Anaconda
3. Install R